# Django ORM calculations between records

Tags: django, pandas, django-models, django-queryset

Is it possible to perform calculations ***between*** records in a Django query?

I know how to perform calculations ***across*** records (e.g. data_a + data_b).  Is there way to perform say the percent change between data_a row 0 and row 4 (i.e. 09-30-17 and 09-30-16)?

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
|   date    | data_a | data_b |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 09-30-17  |    100 |    200 |
| 06-30-17  |     95 |    220 |
| 03-31-17  |     85 |    205 |
| 12-31-16  |     80 |    215 |
| 09-30-16  |     75 |    195 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

I am currently using Pandas to perform these type of calculations, but would like eliminate this additional step if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no row 0 in a Django database, so we'll assume rows 1 and 5.

The general formula for calculation of percentage as expressed in Python is:

```
((b - a) / a) * 100
```

where a is the starting number and b is the ending number. So in your example:

```
a = 100
b = 75
((b - a) / a) * 100
-25.0
```

If your model is called Foo, the queries you want are:

```
(a, b) = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=[id_1, id_2]).values_list('data_a', flat=True)
```

`values_list` says "get just these fields" and `flat=True` means you want a simple list of values, not key/value pairs. By assigning it to the `(a, b)` tuple and using the `__in=` clause, you get to do this as a single query rather than as two.

I would wrap it all up into a standalone function or model method:

```
def pct_change(id_1, id_2):
    # Get a single column from two rows and return percentage of change
    (a, b) = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=[id_1, id_2]).values_list('data_a', flat=True)
    return ((b - a) / a) * 100
```

And then if you know the row IDs in the db for the two rows you want to compare, it's just:

```
print(pct_change(233, 8343))
```

If you'd like to calculate progressively the change between row 1 and row 2, then between row 2 and row 3, and so on, you'd just run this function sequentially for each row in a queryset. Because row IDs might have gaps we can't just use n+1 to compute the next row. Instead, start by getting a list of all the row IDs in a queryset:

```
rows = [r.id for r in Foo.objects.all().order_by('date')]
```

Which evaluates to something like

```
rows = [1,2,3,5,6,9,13]
```

Now for each elem in list and the next elem in list, run our function:

```
for (index, row) in enumerate(rows):
    if index < len(rows):
        current, next_ = row, rows[index + 1]
        print(current, next_)
        print(pct_change(current, next_))
```

Comment: Thanks shacker.  This is a nice solution for getting a single pct_change.  I should have been more explicit, I am trying to calculate the pct_change (among other calcs) for all records in the model.  The new Window functions in Django 2.0 looks like a possible solution.

Comment: Ah! No, your question was pretty specific about showing the change between two records. I've added more code to the answer, showing how to do this progressively for lots of rows at once. However, if the new window functions can help, would love to see an example of how that works here.

Comment: Very well explained, just for the last loop I had to do (len(rows)-1) because index starts at 0

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a Database cursor raw SQL 
(see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/)

combined with a **Lag() window function** as so:

```
result = cursor.execute("""
    select date, 
       data_a - lag(data_a) over (order by date) as data_change,
from foo;""")
```

This is the general idea, you might need to change it according to your needs.